# Unity Random Map Generator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a random map generator in Unity. Currently, I have one prefab, and I'm instantiating it at random positions. However, some of them overlap in the same position. What I want is for it to check if there's something at its position with "isTouching," and if there is, it should generate a new random position until "isTouching" becomes false.

```
public GameObject prefab1;
public bool isPrefab1Touching;

private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Instantiate(prefab1,prefab1Random(),Quaternion.identity);         
        }
    }

    public Vector3 prefab1Random()
    {
        int randomx = Random.Range(0,10);
        int randomy = Random.Range(0,10);
        Vector3 prefab1Position = new Vector3(randomx, randomy);

        isPrefab1Touching = Physics2D.OverlapBox(prefab1.transform.position, new Vector2(1,1), 0f);

        return prefab1Position;
    }
```

Would it be a good idea to store these positions in a list? What approach should I try?

Comment: `it should generate a new random position until "isTouching" becomes false.` well nothing in your code is doing that ... you never do anything at all with `isPrefab1Touching` .. for instance I would expect some `while` loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't completely clear to me what your code is intended to do, or what issue you've run into. (Do you want to instantiate one prefab every time you press the `A` key, or is that just for testing?).

Anyways, I think I get the gist so I'll answer as best I can.

When procedurally generating an environment, It isn't a great idea to generate prefabs one-by-one IMO. For this specific example, I would generate a list of unique prefab positions first, and then instantiate one prefab at each position.

For example, a quite naïve solution could be the following, which uses a HashSet to keep track of the already generated prefab positions:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// generate the map all at once
private void Start() {
    private List<Vector3> prefabPostions = GeneratePrefabPositions(5);
    foreach (Vector3 pos in prefabPositions) {
        Instantiate(prefab1, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

private List<Vector3> GeneratePrefabPositions(int numPrefabs) {
    HashSet<Vector3> positions = new HashSet<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numPrefabs; i++) {
        // generate a unique prefab position for each prefab
        Vector3 currentPos;
        do {
            int randomX = Random.Range(0,10);
            int randomY = Random.Range(0,10);
            currentPos = new Vector3(randomX, randomY);
        } 
        while (positions.Contains(currentPos));
        positions.Add(currentPos);
    }
    return positions.ToList();
}
```

Realistically, there are infinte ways to randomly generate environments. What you choose depends on your performance, gameplay, and artistic needs. There are dozens of good guides and tutorials online.

Comment: I think the drawback of having only the positions first there is no guarantee that those prefabs are not maybe big enough to still overlap. Something OP's code is trying to tackle using the actual physics collider overlaps (of course we can argue that in this case OP's objects seem to be 1x1 unit anyway) in which case using `Vector3Int` or even `Vector2Int` would probably be better